# What algorithm does Azure uses while Autoscaling the AppServices?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Just curious to know, We've an Azure AppService running in Production which has Scale out settings like Minimum 3 instances and Maximum 4 instances upon CPU usage > 75%.

As far I could tell, there is no load balancer configured in our Production environment. Learnt that Azure has in-built routing mechanism which routes the requests to any of the instances, but couldn't find what algorithm it uses to route the requests?

Any idea on this?

Possible algorithms could be Least Response Time? Round Robin? Weighted Round Robin?

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses Least Request Time algorithm.
Load balancing configuration is not public, thus, you cannot set this in an easy way, however you can do it by setting it in the ARM template,

You can check the ARM template schema:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/main/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json#L5841

```
"loadBalancing": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "WeightedRoundRobin",
            "LeastRequests",
            "LeastResponseTime",
            "WeightedTotalTraffic",
            "RequestHash"
          ]
        },
        {
          "$ref": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/common/definitions.json#/definitions/expression"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Site load balancing."
    }
```